# Add Dynamic Attribute Title to the Query Returned In Sub Select

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, html-select

I'm trying to add the attribute, Title, to the Option tag returned in a dynamically generated query in this jQuery function. This is a sub-Select that gets populated from another Select element on the Form. The variable for the Title attribute is #SystemDescription# and it already exists in the query called from the function in the Component.

Example of what it is currently:

```
<option value="#systemid#">#system#</option>
```

Example of what I need it to be:

```
<option value="#systemid#" title="#SystemDescription#">#system#</option>
```

How do I add it to this currently working jQuery function:

```
$('#orderpdm').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<cfoutput>#Application.URL#/#Application.directory#</cfoutput>/cfc/order.cfc?method=GetSystemListSelect',
        data: {PdMID: this.options[this.selectedIndex].value},
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(rtnData) {
            $("#orderpdm option:first-child").attr("disabled", "true");
            $('#systemid').empty();
            $('#systemid').append($("<option value='' selected>-- Select Sub-System --</option>"));
            $.each(rtnData.SELECTLIST, function(key, value) {
                $('#systemid').append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value", value).text(key));
            });         
        },//success
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $.error(errorThrown);
        }//error
    });//ajax
});
```

Comment: I suspect it can be done very similarly to how you are adding the `value`.

Comment: Well this isn't my code and I'm not a jQuery person. I'm a Coldfusion Developer modifying existing code. How would the syntax look for what you describe?

Comment: What does `rtnData.SELECTLIST` look like?

Comment: A query of the Sub Systems associated with the main System that is selected in the main Select element. Specifically the ID, Name, and Description of each Sub System are brought back in the query.

Comment: Can you share an example of the raw `rtnData`? I don't understand how your currently working example can be setting the `value` if `value` is an object. ie., What is the output of `console.log(rtnData.SELECTLIST);`?

Comment: LGN: 36
​"MON-B": 28
​XLK: 40
​"SOSC-B": 17
​"GOSC-L": 29
​"NOSC-D": 56
YEG: 23
​RNT: 24 BFR: 69

Comment: I don't see any descriptions. Where do you expect them to come from?

Comment: I mentioned that in the question "The variable for the Title attribute is #SystemDescription# and it already exists in the query called from the function in the Component." The same table SystemID and System are coming from.

Comment: I won't be able to help you. I do not understand what you are trying to tell me. It is unclear to me where this description is supposed to come from.

Comment: The line in the code the brings the data back is:  url: '<cfoutput>#Application.URL#/#Application.directory#</cfoutput>/cfc/order.cfc?method=GetSystemListSelect',

Comment: What I need to know how to do is to take the other piece of data, SystemDescription, and put in in jQuery here and spit it out. So it starts with getting it into rtnData.SELECTLIST

Comment: The descriptions would need to exist in the response from your API endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done and was. I got the answer elsewhere. Although I was half way there with adding it to the query in the function and trying to alter the attribute. Look at the line that has the .attr. Notice the other attribute is chained to the existing attribute. Within the 2 parenthesis. Also, there are no pound signs with the variable like there usually is in Coldfusion. That's why and where I was stuck on the jQuery syntax nonsense.

```
$('#orderpdm').on('change', function() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<cfoutput>#Application.URL#/#Application.directory#</cfoutput>/cfc/order.cfc?method=GetSystemListSelect',
    data: {PdMID: this.options[this.selectedIndex].value},
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(rtnData) {
        $("#orderpdm option:first-child").attr("disabled", "true");
            $('#systemid').empty();
            $('#systemid').append($("<option value='' selected>-- Select Sub-System --</option>"));
            $.each(rtnData.DATA, function(key, value) {
                $('#systemid').append($(`<option></option>`)
                .attr("value", value["SystemID"]).text(value["System"]).attr("title",value["SystemDescription"]));
            });         
        },//success
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $.error(errorThrown);
        }//error
    });//ajax
}); 

$('#cancelButton').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href = 'sordsDashboard.cfm';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This is more of a comment than an answer

HTML `<select>` does not do what you are expecting. Consider

```
<select title="Animal">
    <option title="Cat" selected>Kitten</option>
    <option title="Dog">Puppy</option>
</select>
```

If you hover over the select, you will get a tooltip of **Animal**

If you really wanted to change the tooltip, you would have to reach all the way up to the `<select>`

Comment: The Select is Multiple, so the user has the ability to hover over the various options.

Comment: Why don't you simply add the System Description to the System information that is already being displayed?

Comment: I like that approach rather than tinkering with the title.